# Raw IL in .NET Standard Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cil, .net-standard, csproj

With the help of the [IL Support](https://github.com/ins0mniaque/ILSupport) VS extension, it was possible to write raw IL in a `.csproj` file targeting the .NET Framework.  This extension requires using the old `.csproj` format to properly allow the IL to "compile". Is it possible to write raw IL in a .NET Standard project using the new `.csproj` format? Or perhaps use the old `.csproj` format but still target .NET Standard?

EDIT: [IL Support v2.4 (VS Extension)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ins0mniaque.ILSupport) has been released with support for the new project format, including .NET Standard and .NET Core.

Comment: This might be a question better suited for the extension's contributors/maintainers.

Comment: @JoeSewell I was thinking there might be another way to do this, but updating the extension is definitely a solution.  In fact, I did just that in a fork of the extension here: https://github.com/jmccormi7/ILSupport.  I will post a complete answer once my pull request gets accepted and deployed

Comment: What a neat project.  Thanks for sharing this, @jeff17237.  I love finding new things like this on SO.